Cannot get hx-swap-oob to work with fasthtml
I'm trying to use hx-swap-oob with HTMX via fasthtml, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's my code:
Div(None, hx_swap_oob=True)

This renders as:
<div hx-swap-oob></div>

What am I doing wrong?

The issue is due to how True on kwargs is handled in fasthtml.
hx_swap_oob=True is interpreted simply as "add the hx-swap-oob attribute without value."
However, for the out of bound swap to work, a value of "true" is required.
This can be achieved by setting hx_swap_oob="true", i.e. the solution is:
Div(None, hx_swap_oob="true")

which will render as
<div hx-swap-oob="true"></div>

